# IReport combine Landscape and Portrait orientation

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, ireport

Someone know one mode for combine the Landscape and Portrait orientation in same report, on IReport? Remembering that I want a PDF document as a result.

Thanks,

Cleber Alberto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is impossible with just iReport and JasperReports API. 
The `orientation` property is determined for the whole report, not for a part of it.

Even JR API allows to set `orientation` property only for report:

```
JasperDesign.setOrientation(OrientationEnum orientationValue)
```

- [sets the report orientation](http://file:///D:/distrib/ireport/4.1.2/jasperreports-4.1.2-project.tar/jasperreports-4.1.2/dist/docs/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html#setOrientation%28net.sf.jasperreports.engine.type.OrientationEnum%29)

May be [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/) can help you to solve this problem.
The quote from [DJ site](http://dynamicjasper.com/features/):

> Automatic report layout: Just define a minimum set of options and DJ
>   will take care of the layout. It’s not an issue to generate the same
>   report for different page sizes and orientation many more!

You can try to use this method from DJ API:

```
public DynamicReportBuilder DynamicReportBuilder.setPageSizeAndOrientation(Page page)
```

- [Defines the page size and orientation. Common pages size and orientation are constants of ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.constants.Page](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/ar/com/fdvs/dj/domain/builders/DynamicReportBuilder.html#setPageSizeAndOrientation%28ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.constants.Page%29)